# How to merge new buffer to old buffer in scala?

Tags: scala, merge, buffer

[image: fig]

I try to merge new data to old buffer when refreshing.

Update or insert is accroding the "id" attr.

Could someone tell me how to do it in scala?

```
def merge(oldBuf: Buffer[java.util.Map[String, Value]], newBuf: Buffer[java.util.Map[String, Value]]) { 
      // loop newBuffer{
             // val item = newBuf(n)
             // val id = item.get("id")   
             // if same id found in oldBuf:
             //    update new [Value] to the old item in oldBuf
             // else (can not found this id in oldBuf)
             //    add this new item to oldBuf 
        //}
          return oldBuf
}
```

Comment: Please add the source for `Buffer`. Is the buffer really parameterized by a Java `Map`? Is there a reason for using Java's Map?

Comment: Will the two `Buffer`s be the same length and will the elements line up so that `newBuffer(0)` only has to look at `oldBuffer(0)` when evaluating if it should update or insert or will the entire old buffer need to be scanned for each iteration of newBuffer?

Comment: oldBuf and newBuf are different length,  use Java Map cas there are return by java method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Java's `Map`, then try `putAll`:

```
import java.util

object Buf extends App {
  val oldBuf = new util.HashMap[Int, String]()
  oldBuf.put(1, "1")
  oldBuf.put(2, "2")
  oldBuf.put(3, "3")
  oldBuf.put(4, "4")

  val newBuf = new util.HashMap[Int, String]()
  newBuf.put(4, "4 new")
  newBuf.put(5, "5")

  oldBuf.putAll(newBuf)
  println(oldBuf)
}
```

If you have a Scala `Map`:

```
import scala.collection._

val oldBuf = mutable.Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
val newBuf = immutable.Map("a" -> 3, "c" -> 4)

oldBuf ++= newBuf
```

so there is no difference.

Generally speaking I suggest converting any Java collection to a Scala collection, before you start processing in Scala (if your long term goal is to replace all Java code). If you use Java collections in Scala in your algorithms, they might stay there for good.